How to understand $ \operatorname{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F) $ "categorially"?
Let $\Omega | F$ be a field extension, $K_1, K_2$ finite Galois extensions of $F$. Proposition 14.21 from Dummit and Foote's book Abstract Algebra claims that
$$
\operatorname{Gal} (K_1 K_2 | F) \simeq \{ (\sigma_1, \sigma_2) \in \operatorname{Gal} (K_1 | F) \times \operatorname{Gal}(K_2 | F) \mid \sigma_1 |_{K_1 \cap K_2} = \sigma_2 |_{K_1 \cap K_2} \}.
$$
It is easy to check that it is the fibered product of $\operatorname{Gal} (K_1 | F)$ and $\operatorname{Gal} (K_2 | F)$ with respect to $\operatorname{Gal} (K_1 \cap K_2 | F)$. That is to say, the following diagram is cartisian(i.e. a pull-back diagram):

Since $K_1 \cap K_2$ and $K_1 K_2$ are somehow "symmetric", I wonder what
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F)
$$
is? I know that by Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, one can descript $\operatorname{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F)$ by the following isomorphism:
$$
\operatorname{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F) \simeq \operatorname{Gal}(K_1 K_2 | F) / \operatorname{Gal}(K_1 K_2 | K_1 \cap K_2).
$$
But it seems not quite "categorial". Is is possible to explain it more "categorially"?

The notion you are looking for is the co-product. If you have two maps $\textrm{Gal}(K_1 |F) \rightarrow \textrm{Gal}(L|F) \leftarrow \textrm{Gal}(K_2|F)$, then there is a unique map $\textrm{Gal}(L|F) \rightarrow \textrm{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F)$ wich commutes with the canonical restrictions $\textrm{Gal}(K_1 | F) \rightarrow \textrm{Gal}(K_1 \cap K_2 | F) \leftarrow \textrm{Gal}(K_2 | F)$.

This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer. This brings extra visibility to the answer und puts the question off the unanswered list.

@EnguerrandMoulinier Coproduct requires arbitrary group $G$ instead of $\operatorname{Gal}(L | F)$. Besides, when you choose a group $G$ and two group homomorphsims, it is quite difficult to find the unique group homomorphsim factoring through.

@Long-PingLi I think you did a pretty good job of describing things categorically using Pullback definition, but what more are you looking for?  This sounds like an X,Y,Z problem in the site's T&C.  We need more data from you...
